# It is possible to query a queue or add a propertie to check if a job with certain property already exists on queue in BULLMQ library

Tags: javascript, node.js, queue, message-queue, bullmq

My question is simple. I just wanna to know if is possible to know is a job with certain propertie in jobData is already on BULLMQ queue. In docs there's nothing about this an didn't found anything about this situation on internet :/
Any  info is very very helfull.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know the queue name? If you know the queue name, you can query the list of jobs, using [getJobs](https://api.docs.bullmq.io/classes/QueueGetters.html#getJobs) and get the data.